# table not responsive on small screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I have following html for my table, but it is adding horizontal scroll on small screen...please help me..how to remove that scroll and make table completely responsive. Thanks.

```
<div class="table-responsive col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-capitalize" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <tr style="background-color :black; color: white">
        <th>Sr.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Expense Detail</th>
        <th>Expense Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>aamir shoeb</td>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>2016-04-09</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>aamir shoeb</td>
            <td>hjk</td>
            <td>2016-04-09</td>
            <td>57</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>aamir shoeb</td>
            <td>uuu</td>
            <td>2016-04-10</td>
            <td>56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="success">
        <td colspan="3" style="visibility: hidden"></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>1222</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with `table` and responsive needs. Here is one way to do it, removing horizontal scroll on mobile as you wish :

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/79xyqwu9/4/)

> CSS

```
@media (max-width:480px ){
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    tr td {
      text-align: center; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    tr td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
    }
}
```